# $P[X+Y \in \Gamma \mid Y=y]=P[X+y \in \Gamma] \text{ for } PY^{-1} \text{-a.s.} y \in \mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

Let $X,Y$ be two random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ taking values in $\mathbb{R}^d, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that $X$ is independent of $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{F}$ and $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable. I am trying to show that for a borel set $\Gamma \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$

$$
P[X+Y \in \Gamma \mid Y=y]=P[X+y \in \Gamma] \text{ for } PY^{-1} \text{-a.s.} y \in  \mathbb{R}^d
$$
Can I write that

$ P[X+Y \in \Gamma \mid Y=y]=\frac{P[X+Y \in \Gamma, Y=y]}{P[Y=y]}= \frac{P[X+y \in \Gamma, Y=y]}{P[Y=y]}=  \frac{P[X+y \in \Gamma] P[ Y=y]}{P[Y=y]} = P[X+y \in \Gamma]$

The problem is I cannot use this definition of conditonal probability if $P[Y=y]$ has measure zero. how could i resolve this issue?
I am studying the markov property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is direct that: $$P(X+Y\in\Gamma\mid Y=y)=P(X+y\in\Gamma\mid Y=y)$$

From $X$ being independent of $\mathcal G$ and $Y$ being $\mathcal G$-measurable it follows that $X$ and $Y$ are independent so that also: $$P(X+y\in\Gamma\mid Y=y)=P(X+y\in\Gamma)$$

Comment: But the first equality you wrote follows as a consequence of what I wrote in my question ? And  the last equality to conclude that you wrote is true even when the measure of $\{Y=y\}$ is zero ? I apologize if the questions are stupid . I do understand your arguments but I just want to understand if what I wrote in a sense agreed with your assertions or if there is some problem in my argument .

Comment: The first equality is *direct* in the sense that under condition $Y=y$ the events $X+Y\in\Gamma$ and $X+y\in\Gamma$ are exactly the same. Concerning the second: if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then informally $Y$ has no influence on the distribution of $X+y$ (where $y$ only denotes a constant). Formally it can be proved that the constant $P(X+y\in\Gamma)=\mathbb E\mathbf1_{X+y\in\Gamma}$ satisfies all conditions on $\mathbb E[\mathbb1_{X+y\in\Gamma}\mid Y]$.